# Magento 1.9 : How to add popup window in custom tab grid adminhtml

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, customer-grid

- Popup window on adminhtml grid signature column now plase check it screen short

[image]

Comment: you need to open popup window when image is clicked? and which content you want to show into that?

Comment: image will be display in popup window.

Comment: magento provide default popup window